# Doubt : Invariance in Geometry

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

I was working my way through some Proof Problems in [Discrete Maths by Rosen](http://www.flipkart.com/discrete-mathematics-its-applications-combinatorics-graph-theory-english-7th/p/itmdwxxszhczjrnf), when I came across the following question:

> What Geometric proposition ( having an invariant property ) does this following diagram prove?

[image]

***My question:***

What proposition / axiom is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "if NA touches the circle at A, the angle inside the alternate segment (i.e. $\angle H$) is equal to $\angle NAB$".

The short form to name this theorem is (Angle in alternate segment).

The first figure serves as a proof of this theorem but the red lines are a bit off-centered.

Comment: Thanks @Mick , i got it :)